# "Operation must use an updateable query" from compiled app but not while debugging

Tags: c#, ms-access, jet

"Operation must use an updateable query".

I have an old application with an Access database (Access 2003), but the front end is written in C#.NET (4.5).

The database is over 10 years old, and the C# front-end has worked fine for around 7 years.  I wrote it myself, so I am familiar with the internals.

Within the last two weeks, I have started getting the error listed above whenever any attempt to update or insert rows occurs.  I had made no changes to the program in over 2 years.

I thought, "no problem, I am a programmer, I'll debug it".  Interestingly, when I run inside visual studio, the program works fine.  I get no errors.  But even after recompiling, then upgrading from VS2010 to VS2012 and form .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5, I continue to get the error above unless I am running inside Visual Studio.  Note: this is not a web application.  It is a stand-alone windows application.

I have done a google search and have found other cases where people are getting this same error, but none seem to match the problem I am having.

All my rows have primary keys that are auto-increment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you double-checked that you're hitting the exact same database file while debugging? (Re: the common  "database in the same folder as the .exe" problem that manifests itself after deployment.) Is the database file on a network share? If so, is it a real Windows SMB share or could it be a third-party file sharing appliance that might be running Linux (specifically Samba)? Done a Compact and Repair on the database and then verified that no Primary Key indexes have been inadvertently dropped as a result? (I've seen that with Samba shares.)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  There has been no compact and repair.  I did go back and check primary keys.  Not on all tables, but on a few specific tables before trying a specific operation on just that table.  The database is accessed via ODBC connection and is definitely hitting the same place.  When I run through VS it works.  But when I run the recently compiled version from the exact same location that VS would get it, it does not work.

Comment: Update: This seems to have something to do with Access 2003 no longer being supported.  I am in the process of converting the database to MS SQL since that get be attained for free.